# MessageError: TypeError: Could not connect to the server

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to download the dataset from Google Colab with the code:

```
from google.colab import files
drive.mount('drive')
df.to_csv('df.csv') 
files.download('df.csv')
```

and it returned

```
MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-c43df340357d> in <module>()
      2 drive.mount('drive')
      3 df.to_csv('df.csv')
----> 4 files.download('df.csv')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 

MessageError: TypeError: Could not connect to the server.
```

I had never experienced this error before and there was no similar questions on the Internet.
Any help is appreciated.